# The app icon set "AppIcon" has 8 unassigned Children?

Tags: ios, xcode

[This is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLh9b.jpg), and everything is fine, but when I exit from Xcode it shows some error, and also the AppIcon drops some images as Unassigned children, see the [second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gK8c.png)

Now, see when i exit from Xcode, i don't now what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It's an Xcode bug, sometimes it happens. Clean Xcode (command+alt+shift+K), Quit Xcode and then check if it works for you or not.